# How can i position the colums in my matrix evenly?

Tags: java, matrix

[image]

```
package SinemaSalonu;

public class SinemaSalonu {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[][] matrix = new int[10][20];
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            matrix[k][0] = k + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + matrix[i][j] + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();

        }

        System.out.println("\n\n" + "                        " + "P E R D E");

    }
}
```

when i run this code the resulting matrix' last row is not centered with others cause of the number "10" in the last row. it caused the row to slightly shift to the right. i want to fix this and center each row.

Comment: when i run the code the last row of my matrix is not properly aligned with other rows. how can  i fix this?

Comment: A little more info would go a long way here. Can you edit the question to show us what you are expecting to see vs what you actually see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to align the lines with a single digit with the lines that start with two digit replace your printing:

```
System.out.print(" " + matrix[i][j] + " ");
```

with:

```
int n = matrix[i][j];
System.out.print(" " + (n < 10 ? " " + n :  n) );
```

It will add an extra space before each line that starts with a single digit.

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: what is the "n" here?